Why does DB upgrade freeze on message "Executed: Update all reserved message templates"?
In all recent upgrades of CiviCRM Wordpress (to 5.71.x, 5.72.x and 5.73.0), the DB upgrade process executing URL
https://<mysite>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fupgrade%2Fqueue%2Frunner&reset=1&qrid=CRM_Upgrade

freezes on message [Executed: Update all reserved message templates].
Issuing again the URL above solves the problem, but I wonder why I need to issue this URL twice. I am using Firefox as browser.

You'll probably find an error in ConfigAndLog. If not, it does a cache clear (several times actually) after that so maybe it's just slow. Or, you can turn on backtrace under admin - system settings - debugging, and then open the browser console network tab while doing the upgrade. If it's crashing you'll see an error 500, and you can click on the response subtab to see the stacktrace.

@Demerit Would it make sense to enter your comment as an answer, as it seems to be one, and a good one at that?

Thanks. Sure why not.

You'll probably find an error in ConfigAndLog. If not, it does a cache clear (several times actually) after that so maybe it's just slow. Or, you can turn on backtrace under admin - system settings - debugging, and then open the browser console network tab while doing the upgrade. If it's crashing you'll see an error 500, and you can click on the response subtab to see the stacktrace.
